# HQL order by type()

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

For example, I have a base entity called 'MyEntityParent' and two sub types 'ZChild' and 'AChild'.

When using the following HQL, this will sort the result list by the type's internal integer value (same as the special class property):

```
select e from MyEntityParent e
order by type(e)
```

However, I need to sort the result list by their entity type's name. I.e., first, instances of type 'AChild', then, instances of type 'ZChild'.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You could "hack" it to do this way by setting their type identifiers in natural order, like "A" will come before "Z".

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the 'natural order' of the types, the hibernate mapping is generated automatically at runtime. I cannot change the generation process of that tool...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select e from MyEntityParent e order by e.class
```

From the Hibernate 3.6 documentation:

> The special property class accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where

But this is deprecated in Hibernate 4.1

Also this is not exactly your wish as it returns the discriminator value, not the exact type name if i read the docs correctly.

Comment: Yes, 'order by type(e)' seems to be the same as 'order by e.class' which is what I meant by "internal integer value" == "discriminator value".

Comment: Hmkay, I was wandering what the internal integer value might have been ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward solution, because HQL is translated to SQL and database is not aware of how the value maps to the name of the class. There is way to make it, but it is not nice:

- Query gets complex, because we have to define order in query.
- Select list contains additional value that defines order, so we cannot return list of entities.
- When model changes, query should be modified

Query is:

```
SELECT e,
  CASE TYPE(e) WHEN AChild THEN 1
               WHEN ZChild THEN 2
               ELSE 3 
  END AS orderValue
FROM MyEntityParent e ORDER BY orderValue
```

And as said, result is no more list of entities, it is list of object arrays, so accessing entity is bit more hard. Entity itself is first item in array (index 0) and ordedValue in second:

```
 List<Object[]> result = em.createQuery("JPQL given above").getResultList();
 for (Object[] resultRow : result) {
     MyEntityParent myEntityParent = (MyEntityParent) resultRow[0];
 }
```

Solution is valid JPQL, so it is not Hibernate specific, but works also with other JPA providers.